# Bootstrap collapse display one at a time

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I am currently having some issues with the Bootstrap collapse, as I want it to show only one div at a time. However, now it just displays all three when I click them. I want to be able to click one button, and hide the others if there's any open. How can I do this?

This is my code so far:

```
 <div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar" aria-label="Toolbar with button groups">
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg m-auto mt-5" role="group" aria-label="First group">
              <button type="button" class="btn active btn-secondary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseInformation" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseInformation"><span class="content">Go one</span></button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseCampus" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseCampus"><span class="content">Go two</span></button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseNearby" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseNearby"><span class="content">Go three</span></button>
            </div>
          </div>




<div id="accordion" role="tablist">
          <div class="collapse-information collapse show w-75 m-auto" role="tab" id="collapseInformation">
              <div class="card card-body">
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam congue laoreet quam, eu convallis tortor condimentum nec. Pellentesque sed felis id ex pellentesque ultrices. Aenean in tempor lorem, eu porta enim. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nulla sit amet congue dolor, id porta urna. Suspendisse vel libero eleifend, accumsan nunc id, vulputate ligula. Nunc eleifend dictum velit, vel euismod augue pretium et.

                  Proin rhoncus odio eleifend finibus mattis. Morbi purus odio, aliquam non augue quis, viverra iaculis velit. Fusce dictum elit vel venenatis posuere. Donec nisl nibh, semper vel lacus et, facilisis tempor velit. Proin ullamcorper, diam ac lobortis venenatis, lorem lectus dapibus nulla, eget dapibus leo ex ut leo. Suspendisse sed nisl sollicitudin, vulputate ipsum a, commodo tortor. In bibendum placerat nibh non congue. Curabitur condimentum dolor turpis, vel pharetra dui egestas a. Integer consequat accumsan rutrum. Morbi et felis quam. Sed suscipit placerat dolor, nec vulputate dolor. Maecenas porta ex ut arcu mattis, sit amet convallis urna scelerisque.</div>
          </div>

          <div class="collapse-campus collapse w-75 m-auto" role="tab" id="collapseCampus">
              <div class="card card-body">
                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
              </div>
          </div>

          <div class="collapse-nearby collapse w-75 m-auto" role="tab" id="collapseNearby">
              <div class="card card-body">
                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is clearly described in the [Bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/collapse/#options)

Comment: @ZimSystem That might be the case, but I didn't notice it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's is simple issue just use **data-parent="#accordion"** in your html

**You Can Try this Code here..**

or you try in jsfiddle [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gwvmty0f/)

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">



 <div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar" aria-label="Toolbar with button groups">
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg m-auto mt-5" role="group" aria-label="First group">
              <button type="button" class="btn active btn-secondary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseInformation" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseInformation"><span class="content">Go one</span></button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseCampus" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseCampus"><span class="content">Go two</span></button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseNearby" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseNearby"><span class="content">Go three</span></button>
            </div>
          </div>




<div id="accordion" role="tablist">
          <div class="collapse-information collapse show w-75 m-auto" role="tab" id="collapseInformation" data-parent="#accordion">
              <div class="card card-body">
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam congue laoreet quam, eu convallis tortor condimentum nec. Pellentesque sed felis id ex pellentesque ultrices. Aenean in tempor lorem, eu porta enim. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nulla sit amet congue dolor, id porta urna. Suspendisse vel libero eleifend, accumsan nunc id, vulputate ligula. Nunc eleifend dictum velit, vel euismod augue pretium et.

                  Proin rhoncus odio eleifend finibus mattis. Morbi purus odio, aliquam non augue quis, viverra iaculis velit. Fusce dictum elit vel venenatis posuere. Donec nisl nibh, semper vel lacus et, facilisis tempor velit. Proin ullamcorper, diam ac lobortis venenatis, lorem lectus dapibus nulla, eget dapibus leo ex ut leo. Suspendisse sed nisl sollicitudin, vulputate ipsum a, commodo tortor. In bibendum placerat nibh non congue. Curabitur condimentum dolor turpis, vel pharetra dui egestas a. Integer consequat accumsan rutrum. Morbi et felis quam. Sed suscipit placerat dolor, nec vulputate dolor. Maecenas porta ex ut arcu mattis, sit amet convallis urna scelerisque.</div>
          </div>

          <div class="collapse-campus collapse w-75 m-auto" role="tab" id="collapseCampus" data-parent="#accordion">
              <div class="card card-body">
                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
              </div>
          </div>

          <div class="collapse-nearby collapse w-75 m-auto" role="tab" id="collapseNearby" data-parent="#accordion">
              <div class="card card-body">
                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: @Md Abu Sayed i just wanted to ask does including specific classes does it  or the architecture of the accordion has changed it isnot ???

Comment: you can change any class See this link https://jsfiddle.net/gwvmty0f/1/